# where does VirtualBox create partitions on mac for fedora installation?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, fedora

I have downloaded the fedora iso image and trying to install it using virtual box on my mac. I dedicated a space of 40GB for my hard drive. Now I get this pop up message, I am worried if it will delete my data on hard-drive. I have enough free-space left on my hard-drive. but I don't want this partion to erase my exisiting data.

where is the partition created on file system.(`ATA VBOX HARDDISK`). Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a virtual hard-disk in the **host** operating system (In virtualBox) will not overwrite any files on your hard drive. It will only utilize unused space on your disk. Overwriting the hard-disk in the **guest** operating system will not delete any files in the **host**, but it will overwrite/wipe files in the virtual hard disk (**guest** OS files).